# Hide element if data contains specific piece of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a possibility to hide elements if the data contains a piece of text?

For example: Hide the divs that it's data contains "-en"

```html
<div class="check" data-value="example-en"></div>
<div class="check" data-value="check-en"></div>
<div class="check" data-value="example2-en"></div>
<div class="check" data-value="check-fr"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use :contains selector in this case to hide the div !

Comment: i've read people saying that in data you can't not use :contains, could you use an example please? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with either css or Javascript.

**CSS**

```
[data-value*="-en"] {
  display: none;
}
```

And if you wanted to do it based on classes.

```
[class*="-en"] {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-value*="-en"]').forEach((elem) => elem.style.display = 'none');
```

Comment: Yup, CSS's worked :) Many thanks! And another question, is :not() working with this? Could :not([data-value....) work?

Comment: Using `:not()` could work, but your selector list could end up being quite large depending on how many you want to exclude.

Comment: Thanks @aphextwix Last question (srry lol), is it possible to do the same with classes? Hiding the classes that contains -en? for example: <div class="example-en"></div><div class="example2-de"></div><div class="example3-en"></div>

Just hide the ones that it's class contains -en? Thanks dude

Comment: @Vander - I've updated my answer to show an example of using classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
div[data-value*="-en"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="check" data-value="check-en">1</div>
<div class="check" data-value="check-en">2</div>
<div class="check" data-value="check-fr">3</div>
<div class="check" data-value="check-fr">4</div>
```

Comment: Hi gerard, thanks for your reply. Thing is that not all datas are "check", there is other with other names and "-en" to the end... could it be a global solution? Thanks